# Unable to build array in component data after created event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I haven't worked with Vue.Js in some time so my memory is a little rusty. I seem to have an issue where I unable to modify a data array within a function called within the created hook.

What I'm trying to do is build a multidimensional array with the months of the year as the key, and the data (this.data.data which is a prop) as the value. This is a shortened version of the component. I know this.data.data is returning the array of objects required and `console.log(this.fixtures);` also outputs the built data.

The code for the project can be seen below.

```
data: function(){
    return {
        fixtures: []
    }

},

created() {

    this.setFixtureMonths(this.data.data);

    console.log(this.fixtures);
},

methods: {

    setFixtureMonths: function (collection) {

        let vm = this;

        collection.forEach(function(element) {

            let d = new Date(element.date);
            let m = d.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'}).toLocaleLowerCase();


            vm.$set(vm.fixtures, m, element);

        });

    }
}
```

However on render of the view and checking the Vue Devtools extention, I notice that fixtures remains empty even thought it is being logged by the console correctly. Looking through the documentation I'm aware the conventional assignment of array doesn't work, so I've resorted to using `vm.$set` as a means to build the array.

Can someone share some insight for me please on how to get the view to render the fixtures?

Thanks

Comment: `vm.fixtures` is an Array, but it's using the string `m` to index into the Array; that won't do anything in JavaScript since Array indices are always numbers. Should `fixtures` be an Object?

Comment: @Ross Allen and there goes to show why my background is in php, i'll give it a try!

Comment: Cool try doing `fixtures: {}` instead to make it an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Had a slight moment forgetting novice JavaScript principles

replacing:

```
vm.$set(vm.fixtures, m, element);
```

to:

```
vm.fixtures[m] = element;
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on your own answer you can improve your code a little bit by doing the following:

```
setFixtureMonths: function (collection) {
        collection.forEach((element) => {

            let d = new Date(element.date);
            let m = d
                    .toLocaleString('default', {
                        month: 'long'
                    })
                    .toLocaleLowerCase();


            this.$set(vm.fixtures, m, element);

        });
    }
```

by replacing the anonymous function by an arrow function you will have access to the parent context, therefore no need to have `let vm = this;`